# Sales Cloud Einstein

Tags: einstein

My customer uses Salesforce, however wants to use Sales Cloud Einstein. What are the things required for them?

1. Can they use in the same salesforce org
2. Do they need extra licensing
3. Does it require an AppExchange package to be installed

Comment: Einstein in Salesforce is an umbrella naming strategy for a number of products. What specific product are you inquiring about? Here's an [overview](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/get_smart_einstein_feat/get_smart_einstein_feat_tour) of some Einstein capabilities

Comment: I am looking for SalesCloud Einstein capabilities. Is 'Salesforce Einstein's comes as a product which needs to install in Salesforce as an appexchange package?

Comment: The answers to your questions are covered in [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=einstein_sales_setup.htm&type=5) documentation, have a read.